# Font Meta Data - calculate the gap above the capital letter

Tags: html, fonts

Given a TTF or WOFF font which renders in the browser like this (with a css border for demonstration purpose):

[image: Font rendered in the browser]

I extracted the [meta data](https://opentype.js.org/font-inspector.html) of the font and got those information:

```
ascender: 1900
descender: -500
lineGap: 0
advanceWidthMax: 2469
minLeftSideBearing: -1063
minRightSideBearing: -280
xMaxExtent: 2477
unitsPerEm: 2048
xMin: -1063
yMin: -555
xMax: 2477
yMax: 2179
...
```

What would be the proper calculation to get the distance shown in the screenshot?

Comment: Looks like the ascender height: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascender_(typography)

Comment: @Michael_B thanks - afaik the ascender is relative to the baseline.. how would I calculate it from the meta data?

Comment: What you're overall objective?

Comment: @Michael_B Please don't provide a work around I would love to understand how fonts work.

Comment: I wouldn't even know what to provide a workaround for at this point. If your end goal is simply to know the calculation, that's fine. But if your question is an attempt to solve a bigger problem, it would be good to eliminate the [**XY Problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as a possibility.

Comment: Well there is a larger problem.
Actually I would love to get rid of the ascender without using negative top margins to get around the collapsing margin complexity.
I would like to know if moving all glyphs up would get me around that issue.
Right now it looks like it could work quite well but I am using a hardcoded value. So that's why I am asking how I could turn this hardcoded value into a calculation ;)

Comment: Have you considered the CSS `line-height` property?

Comment: Yes but that won't work if the text wraps.

Comment: Some calculations are documented here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height